# Gradle Error: Could not find property file

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle, smartphone

I had posted a previous question and ask this in the comments, but received no response. I have been struggling with finding a solution to this for a couple weeks now.

I am trying to add .jar files to my program for uploading a document in an android app. However, it says gradle was unsuccessful and it could not find property 'file'.

**Here is the error:**

Error:(25, 0) Could not find property 'file' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@41762346.

**Here is the code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashleygreen.healthcareapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile file 'libs/httpclient-4.2.2.jar.zip'
    compile file 'libs/httpmime-4.0.jar.zip'
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `compile file 'libs/httpmime-4.0.jar.zip'`? Gradle can't read zipped jar files...

Comment: I am really new to Android apps and I am trying to create a program that would allow me to upload documents

Comment: Also, I unzipped the files (silly mistake on my part) and it is still showing numerous errors as well as the previous stated one

Comment: You should look up on the maven centrall the path to download your libs, let gradle manage your depencies do not upload files onto the lib folder unless it's a lib that you created, like compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.0' and compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Gradle cannot work with zipped jar files - you'll have to unzip the jar files first.

When you include the line

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This means that any file ending in `.jar` will be included as a dependency as long as it is in the `libs` directory. Therefore there is no need to use either of the last lines (as those libraries are already included via the first line).

However, if you did want to include a single jar file from another directory, you're missing the parentheses after `file`:

```
compile file('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. However, the following worked for me (in android studio 1.5):

```
compile files ('libs/httpclient-4.2.2.jar.zip')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar.zip')
```

Notice it's `files` with an extra 's' with parentheses. Only `file` is not recognized.